# Read XMLNode errors from SoapException

Tags: c#, web-services, soapexception

I have this kind of SoapException

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:WaybillRegistrationFault xmlns:ns1="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                    <errors xmlns:ns2="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                        <code>80000</code>
                        <description>El número de CTG 59455243 ya existe</description>
                    </errors>
                    <errors xmlns:ns2="http://pod.waybillmanagement.ws.industrysystem.com.ar/">
                        <code>1000</code>
                        <description>Unexpected Error</description>
                    </errors>
                </ns1:WaybillRegistrationFault>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How do I read each error? I tried with Detail.InnerText but all the text shows without formatting.
Is there a way of using foreach on the  tag?

Comment: are you familiar with how to Consume a web service and from there my next question would be are you familiar with how to create your own proxy or instance of the web Service ? if so the create an instance of that, if the properties are visible then store each of the inner detail error messages in a List<T> or some other Object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse that xml easily with LinqToXml

```
var errors = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring)
                .Descendants("errors")
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    code = (int)e.Element("code"),
                    desc = (string)e.Element("description")
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: But how do I get to display that in an foreach sentence?

Comment: @cadaov `errors` is a List. I think you know how to iterate on  list using *foreach*. (BTW: your problem in question is about parsing an xml, not how to use *foreach* to iterate over a  list. You can use any c# reference for this)